# DolphinDB: chunks distribution of a dfs table in a cluster

Tags: chunks, dolphindb

How to get the distribution of all the chunks of a dfs table in a cluster with DolphinDB? I've tried `getChunksMeta` but it only returned the chunk information.

Answer (score 0):

Use DolphinDB function `getTabletsMeta()` to view the chunk metadata of the data node. The output includes the information on the data node where the chunk is located. Then encapsulate a query function:

```
def chunkDistribution(dbName, tbName){
    return select count(*) from pnodeRun(getTabletsMeta{"/"+substr(dbName,6)+"/%",tbName,true,-1}) group by node
}
dbName = "dfs://testDB"
tbName = "testTable"
chunkDistribution(dbName, tbName)
```